# Old "first question" displays incorrect information

Tags: bug, review-queues, protected-questions

I came upon https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5629678 just now, which has some confusing content.

First, it alerts me that

> Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully

The question is marked as having 0 votes, and is listed as having been asked 2 hours ago (mousover says it was asked at 2014-08-26 15:18:24Z).  However at a glance the question doesn't actually look spammy.  But here's where it gets weird.

> protected by OneOfOne Aug 10 at 8:07

What?  August 10th?  What sort of 0 rep question needs protection?  And how was it protected before it was posted?  So I load the actual question, [How to distinguish if a file or folder is being dragged prior to it being dropped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25016442/how-to-distinguish-if-a-file-or-folder-is-being-dragged-prior-to-it-being-droppe) and lo and behold, it has *43* votes and was "asked Jul 29 at 13:24".

Presumably this was the OP's first post, and for whatever reason it's just shown up in this queue, but the information being displayed about the question (votes, date, etc.) are clearly incorrect.  Further, it seems like protected questions should be excluded from the review process - they've clearly been audited by a moderator at that point.

Comment: I'm just asking (feel free to tell me I'm wrong, I am trying to learn how to get/use moderation tools as my rep slowly ramps up)..... could it be an audit for you?  the system "re-created" a question to see how you would handle it?

Answer (score 1):

You have been served a *review audit* to see if you are paying attention and not just robo-clicking your way to a badge. The post has been 'massaged' a little to *look* like a first post, that's all.

Congratulations, you paid enough attention. Click *No Action Needed* (the post has stood the test of time), and pass the test.

You could consider the fact that the *protected* banner hasn't been carefully hidden or otherwise altered to not give away the game a bug. But robo-reviewers are really that focused on just clicking through and won't even notice that.

Note that any [15k+ plus user can protect a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions); the question hasn't been vetted by a moderator.

Comment: Fair enough, but this audit seems poor/confusing, particularly since it's protected in the past.  Perhaps the Protected message should be hidden in this case?